# Site Analytics multi-year timeline omits the year

Tags: bug, user-interface, moderator-tools, analytics

On a site where I have the Site Analytics privilege, I asked for a multi-year plot of questions asked per week. The time axis was displayed as follows:

[image: Multi-year timeline]

This is not a particularly useful time axis.  When the time exceeds a year (or perhaps when the time crosses a year boundary at all), the year should be shown, either at each tick mark, or wherever the date crosses a year boundary.